# Protractor: Selenium Server Not getting Started via webdriver-manager start command

Tags: protractor

I am new in using protractor. While installing it, I am getting an error when starting selenium server using 'webdriver-manager start' command.Here is the snapshot of that error: 
[Please click here for the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiApT.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a proxy configured, I think that is now allowing you to establish a connection on the port that you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your info, but there is no proxy configured. The loopback error that is in the snapshot, is it because of the port the selenium server is using is engaged with some other application?